# What does intermittent "Input/output error" suggest?

Tags: 12.04

Lately my Ubuntu 12 system has started acting very strange. Sometimes the computer freezes and then unfreezes 2 minutes later, and other times when I try a basic command like `less` I get the error `bash: /usr/bin/less: Input/output error`. But this is intermittent too. Any suggestions?

Also if I try `sudo reboot` and enter my password, I get

```
sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/plato/7: Read-only file system
```

Before I used to be able to do `sudo reboot` fine.

If I tail `/var/log/syslog` I do see these curious lines:

```
.... ata1: softreset failed (device not ready)
.... ata1: hard resettting link
.... ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at /var/log/syslog, and I have a hunch you'll see a lot of disk-related errors. Input/output error indicates that the system is having trouble reading or writing information, and this is most likely due to damaged storage devices.

Comment: Go to "Disk utility", it will tell you more about the "health" of your hard drive.

Answer (score 5):

Backup your data **NOW**.

Then investigate further, or just head to a computer store to get a new hard drive :)